# Performance benefits of strict aliasing

Tags: c, performance, strict-aliasing

In C, what exactly are the performance benefits that come with observing strict aliasing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a page that describes aliasing very thoroughly [here](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html).

There are also some SO topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262379/when-is-char-safe-for-strict-pointer-aliasing).

To summarize, the compiler cannot assume the value of data when two pointers of different types are accessing the same location (i.e. it must read the value every time and therefore cannot make optimizations).

This only occurs when strict aliasing is not being enforced. Strict aliasing options:

- gcc: **-fstrict-aliasing [default]** and **-fno-strict-aliasing**
- msvc:
  **Strict aliasing is off by default.**
  (If somebody knows how to turn it on,
  please say so.)

---

## Example

Copy-paste this code into main.c:

```
void f(unsigned u)
{
    unsigned short* const bad = (unsigned short*)&u;
} 

int main(void)
{
    f(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Then compile the code with these options:

> gcc main.c -Wall -O2

And you will get:

> main.c:3:
> warning: dereferencing type-punned
> pointer will break strict-aliasing
> rules

Disable aliasing with:

> gcc main.c -fno-strict-aliasing
> -Wall -O2

And the warning goes away. (Or just take out -Wall but...don't compile without it)

Try as I might I could not get MSVC to give me a warning.

Comment: +1, but please make it clear that the compiler cannot make that assumption when strict aliasing is *not* observed.

Comment: Perfect! :) Unfortunate that MSVC++ doesn't seem to have an option for strict aliasing. It does have __restrict and __declspec(restrict) though, which can be used in individual cases.

Comment: Looks like a typo “-fno-strict-aliasing [default] and -fno-strict-aliasing” I'm guessing the default is actually -fstrict-aliasing 
(at least in modern GCC) rather than -fno-strict-aliasing, but in any case one of the two GCC options listed should be -fstrict-aliasing, and right now they both say -fno-strict-aliasing.

Comment: Ha, nice catch, I'm surprised nobody saw that until now.

Comment: default for my gcc is -fno-strict-aliasing (at least, I see a difference in assembly output when I set -fstrict-aliasing over default options)

Comment: The first article linked in the answer (Understanding strict aliasing on Cellperformance.com) can be found here: http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html

Comment: MSVC has the [/Oa and /Ow options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984741(v=vs.71).aspx) but they assume that there's no aliasing whatsoever.

Comment: How much research has been done on the extent to which applying type-based aliasing offers performance benefits that cannot be obtained just as well with `restrict`?  Your first linked article suggests "If a program requires `-fno-strict-alias` one should figure that the programmer probably didn't bother to use `restrict`, but if `restrict` can offer all the performance advantages of type-based aliasing without the semantic limitations, why shouldn't one disable type-based aliasing, especially given that there's no way of knowing how gcc's interpretation of the rules may change in the future?

Comment: Which GCC version prints this? I'm having trouble reproducing the warning with GCC 6 and 7.

Comment: Your example program doesn't dereference any pointer (except that the function call `f(5)` dereferences the function-pointer-valued expression `f`).

Answer (score 2):

The level of performance improvement that will result from applying type-based aliasing will depend upon:

1. The extent to which code caches things in automatic-duration objects, or via the restrict qualifier, indicates that compilers may do so without regard for whether they might be affected by certain pointer-based operations.
2. Whether the aliasing assumptions made by a compiler are consistent with what a programmer needs to do (if they're not, reliable processing would require disabling type-based aliasing, negating any benefits it could otherwise have offered).

Consider the following two code snippets:

```
struct descriptor { uint32_t size; uint16_t *dat; };
void test(struct descriptor *ptr)
{
  for (uint32_t i=0; i < ptr->size; i++)
    ptr->dat[i] = 1234;
}
void test2(struct descriptor *ptr)
{
  int size = ptr->size;
  short *dat = ptr->dat;
  for (uint32_t i=0; i < size; i++)
    dat[i] = 1234;
}
```

In the absence of type-based aliasing rules, a compiler given `test1()` would have to allow for the possibility that `ptr->dat` might point to an address within `ptr->size` or `ptr->dat`.  This would in turn require that it either check whether `ptr->dat` was in range to access those things, or else reload the contents of `ptr->size` and `ptr->dat` on every iteration of the loop.  In this scenario, type-based aliasing rules might allow for a 10x speedup.

On the other hand, a compiler given `test2()` could generate code equivalent to the optimized version of `test1()` without having to care about type-based aliasing rules.  In this case, performing the same operation, type-based aliasing rules would not offer any speedup.

Now consider the following functions:

```
uint32_t *ptr;

void set_bottom_16_bits_and_advance_v1(uint16_t value)
{
  ((uint16_t)ptr)[IS_BIG_ENDIAN] = value;
  ptr++;
}
void set_bottom_16_bits_and_advance_v2(uint16_t value)
{
  ((unsigned char*)ptr)[3*IS_BIG_ENDIAN] = value & 255;
  ((unsigned char*)ptr)[(3*IS_BIG_ENDIAN) ^ 1] = value >> 8;
  ptr++;
}
void test1(unsigned n)
{
  for (unsigned i=0; i<n; i++)
    set_bottom_16_bits_v1(i);
}
void test2(unsigned n, int value)
{
  for (unsigned i=0; i<n; i++)
    set_bottom_16_bits_v2(value);
}
```

If a compiler given `set_bottom_16_bits_and_advance_v1` and `test1` were--even with type-based aliasing enabled--accommodate the possibility that it might modify an object of type `uint32_t` (since its execution makes use of a value of type `uint32_t*`), it would not need to allow for the possibility that `ptr` might hold its own address.  If a compiler could not handle the possibility of the first function accessing a `uint32_t` without disabling type-based aliasing entirely, however, it would need to reload `ptr` on every iteration of the loop.  Almost any compiler(*), with or without type-based aliasing analysis, which is given `set_bottom_16_bits_and_advance_v1` and `test2`, however, would be required to reload `ptr` every time through the loop, reducing to zero any performance benefits type-based aliasing could have offered.

(*) The CompCert C dialect expressly disallows the use of character pointers, or any other pointer-to-integer type, to modify the values of stored pointer object, since making allowance for such accesses would not only degrade performance, but also make it essentially impossible to identify all corner cases that would need to be evaluated to guarantee that the behavior of a compiler's generated machine code will match the specified behavior of the source.

Comment: If the aliasing assumptions are not consistent with what the programmer needs to do, that's a situation in which it the feature is actively harmful.

Comment: @Kaz: In nearly all compilers, it is possible to disable type-based aliasing analysis.  If a programmer enables TBAA only when using compilers that limit their assumptions to those which are consistent with what needs to be done, then a compiler that makes overbroad assumptions will simply need to be used with TBAA disabled.