# What is aliasing and how does it affect performance?

Tags: c++

At the GoingNative event, during the [Interactive Panel](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything-) on Day2 at the 9 minute mark, Chandler Carruth says:

> Pointers create aliasing problems. They slow down your binaries not speed them up.

What does this mean? Can this be illustrated with a (simple) example?

Comment: Why don't you ask Chandler Carruth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [strict aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754929/strict-aliasing)

Comment: Try watching [this](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/). It's actually pretty good. Aliasing is when you take the pointer of an objecct instead of the object himself, as he explains.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: Chandler Carruth explains this himself in this video (39:40-43:54): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eR34r7HOU14

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Aliasing affects performance by preventing the compiler from doing certain optimizations. For example:

```
void foo(int *array,int *size,int *value) {
    for(int i=0;i<*size;++i) {
        array[i] = 2 * *value;
    }
}
```

Looking at this code you might expect that the compiler could load `*value` once outside the loop and then set every element in the array to that value very quickly. But this isn't the case due to aliasing. Because `*value` could be an alias for an element of the array it could change on any given iteration. Therefore the code has to load the value every single iteration, resulting in a potentially large slowdown.

If the variables could not alias then the above code would be equivalent to the following:

```
void foo(int *array,int size,int value) {
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i) {
        array[i] = 2 * value;
    }
}
```

Using LLVM's [online demo](http://llvm.org/demo/) to get the generated code, here are the different results:

**1) With aliasing**

```
foo:                                    # @foo
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    cmpl    $0, (%rsi)
    jle .LBB0_3
# BB#1:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_2:                                # %.lr.ph
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movl    (%rdx), %ecx
    addl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    %ecx, (%rdi,%rax,4)
    incq    %rax
    cmpl    (%rsi), %eax
    jl  .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:                                # %._crit_edge
    ret
    .size   foo, .Ltmp1-foo
    .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end0:
```

---

**2) Without aliasing**

```
foo:                                    # @foo
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    testl   %esi, %esi
    jle .LBB0_3
# BB#1:                                 # %.lr.ph
    addl    %edx, %edx
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movl    %edx, (%rdi)
    addq    $4, %rdi
    decl    %esi
    jne .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:                                # %._crit_edge
    ret
    .size   foo, .Ltmp1-foo
    .cfi_endproc
.Leh_func_end0:
```

You can see that the version with aliasing has to do more work in the loop body (between the labels `LBB0_2` and `LBB0_3`).

Comment: would const keyword helps? for example, `foo(..., const int * value)` instead, which implies that the content of `*value` would not change.

Comment: @bumfo No, I wouldn't expect that to improve anything in this case, because `const` doesn't actually imply that the value won't be changed. All it says is that the function won't change it through that pointer. (Although technically `const` doesn't even mean that much.)

Answer (score 12):

The type of problem Chandler was talking about can be easily illustrated with a simplified `strcpy`:

```
char *stpcpy (char * dest, const char * src);
```

When writing an implementation of this, you might assume that the memory pointed to by `dest` is completely separate from the memory pointed to by `src`. The compiler) might want to optimize it by reading a block of characters from the string pointed to by `src`, and writing all of them at once into `dest`. But if `dest` pointed to one byte ahead of `src`, the behaviour of this would differ from a simple character-by-character copy.

Here the aliasing problem is that `src` can alias `dest`, and the generated code must be made less efficient than it could be if `src` wasn't allowed to alias `dest`.

The real `strcpy` uses an extra keyword, [Restrict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) (which is [technically only part of C, not C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776283/what-does-the-restrict-keyword-mean-in-c), that tells the compiler to assume that `src` and `dest` do not overlap, and this allows the compiler to generate much more efficient code.

---

Here's an even simpler example where we can see a big difference in the assembly:

```
void my_function_1(int* a, int* b, int* c) {
    if (*a) *b = *a;
    if (*a) *c = *a;
}

void my_function_2(int* __restrict a, int* __restrict b, int* __restrict c) {
    if (*a) *b = *a;
    if (*a) *c = *a;
}
```

Assume that this is a simplification of a function where it actually made sense to use two if-statements rather than just `if (*a) { *b=*a; *c=*a; }`, but the intent is the same.

We may assume when writing this that `a != b` because there's some reason why it would make no sense for `my_function` be used like that. But the compiler can't assume that, and does a store of `b` and a re-load of `a` from memory before executing the second line, to cover the case where `b == a`:

```
0000000000400550 <my_function_1>:
  400550:       8b 07                   mov    (%rdi),%eax
  400552:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax                 <= if (*a)
  400554:       74 0a                   je     400560 <my_function_1+0x10>
  400556:       89 06                   mov    %eax,(%rsi)
  400558:       8b 07                   mov    (%rdi),%eax
  40055a:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax                 <= if (*a)
  40055c:       74 02                   je     400560 <my_function_1+0x10>
  40055e:       89 02                   mov    %eax,(%rdx)
  400560:       f3 c3                   repz retq
```

If we remove potential for aliasing by adding `__restrict`, the compiler generates shorter and faster code:

```
0000000000400570 <my_function_2>:
  400570:       8b 07                   mov    (%rdi),%eax
  400572:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
  400574:       74 04                   je     40057a <_Z9my_function_2PiS_S_+0xa>
  400576:       89 06                   mov    %eax,(%rsi)
  400578:       89 02                   mov    %eax,(%rdx)
  40057a:       f3 c3                   repz retq
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following function:

```
void f(float* lhs, float* rhs, float* out, int size) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        out[i] = *lhs + *rhs;
    }
}
```

What's the fastest version of this function? Probably, you hoist `*lhs + *rhs` out of the loop. The problem is what happens when the pointers alias. Imagine what that optimization does if I call it like this:

```
float arr[6] = { ... };
f(arr, arr + 1, arr, 6);
```

As you can see, the problem is that `*lhs + *rhs` cannot be hoisted out of the loop, because `out[i]` modifies their values. In fact, the compiler can't hoist *any* logic out of the loop. So the compiler cannot perform the "obvious" optimization, because if the parameters alias the logic is now incorrect. However, if the floats are taken by value, then the compiler knows they can't alias and can perform the hoist.

Of course, this function is pretty silly, but it demonstrates the point.

Answer (score 1):

a pointer is a value that represents a memory address sometimes 2 pointers can represent the same memory address thats what aliasing is

```
int * p;
*p = 5;

int * alias;
alias = p;
```

the variable `alias` is an alias of p and `*alias` is equal to 5  if you change `*alias` then `*p` changes along with it

Comment: how does this slows down the binary?

Comment: @unexplored Indirection slows down binaries because you don't know what the actual data is until you fetch where the data is. To get the data you need to fetch the address of the data and then you can finally fetch the data which is memory requests (unless cached).

Comment: @JesusRamos correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't it be the same without indirection? I mean when dereferencing `p` in this case, the data is not known until is fetched either.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the compiler optimizer.

Comment: @unexplored Pointers don't allow for optimizations that could normally happen in the case. If you have two pointers to the same thing the compiler will not try to follow them because the results of modification are undefined.

Comment: @JesusRamos Could you clarify what you mean? Under which conditions is it "undefined" to "have two pointers to the same thing"? Aren't explicit allowances made for this being legal, albeit pessimising, so long as the pointers are of compatible types, and illegal if they are not so? I think that's probably what you were saying, but it's not clear.