# C++: Casting from char pointer to struct pointer without committing undefined behavior

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

```
struct S { char A; char B; char C; char D; };
unsigned char x[4] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF };
auto y = (S*) x;
cout << y->A; // undefined behaviour
```

The fourth line here violates [strict aliasing](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/1307), which means that the compiler could decide to play some mean tricks on me. Is there any way to achieve something similar without invoking undefined behaviour?

Comment: The third line does not violate strict aliasing yet. But it would if you later wrote `*y = z;` for example.  If you intend to do something like that it'd be good to have it in the question - as it stands now, your answer is wrong (casting is not undefined behaviour per se).

Comment: You should not cast a `char*` to a `struct*`, you should cast the `struct*` to a `char*` then `copy`.

Comment: I don't think violating strict aliasing means that the compiler may play some mean tricks. In fact compilers (like gcc and clang) provide an option -fno-strict-aliasing that allows you to tell the compiler strict aliasing is not observed in the program. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754929/performance-benefits-of-strict-aliasing) for example.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your question, as I don't understand the problem you're facing. What is the behaviour that you are expecting when casting char pointer to struct pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Casting and dereferencing is undefined behavior.
- Union casting is kosher... in C. In C++ it's undefined behavior.
- `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behavior.

The only legit approach is `memcpy`. A sufficiently smart compiler will optimize it into nothingness, but you really have no guarantees.

Comment: Casting is not undefined behaviour. Derefereferncing of casted pointer - is. Use memcpy.