# Different behavior of shift operator with -O2 and without

Tags: c++, gcc, 64-bit, compiler-optimization, strict-aliasing

Without -O2 this code prints `84 84`, with O2 flag the output is `84 42`. The code was compiled using `gcc 4.4.3.` on 64-bit Linux platform. Why the output for the following code is different?

Note that when compiled with -Os the output is `0 42`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long n = 42;
    int *p = (int *)&n;
    *p <<= 1;
    cout << *p << " " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: g++ 4.5.2 on a x86_64 linux prints `84 84` with -O0, -O1, -O2, -O3, and -Os

Comment: g++ 4.5.0 on 64-bit Windows prints `84 84` with any optimization level.

Comment: I believe the result of this line `int *p = (int *)&n;` depends on endian-ness of the machine!

Comment: Why are you using an `int*` to a `long long`?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the problem with g++ 4.4.4. Looks like the 4.4 branch has a bug/feature that was fixed in 4.5.

Comment: @Nawaz, still, why would optimization mode influence the result?

Comment: @Leonid try compiling with `-fno-strict-aliasing`

Comment: @Cubbi: that's circumventing a language rule... I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: @Leonid: because optimization are taking advantage of the aliasing rule to optimize...

Comment: @Matthieu M. I was going to say that too, but then got distracted reading other SO aliasing threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262379/when-is-char-safe-for-strict-pointer-aliasing

Comment: @Cubbi: yes, it comes up now and then on SO, whether because got bit by it or because they suddenly experience this weird warning message :p

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you use optimization with gcc, it can use certain assumptions based on the type of expressions to avoid repeating unnecessary reads and to allow retaining variables in memory.

Your code has undefined behaviour because you cast a pointer to a `long long` (which gcc allows as an extenstion) to a pointer to an `int` and then manipulate the pointed-to-object as if it were an `int`. A pointer-to-`int` cannot normally point to an object of type `long long` so gcc is allowed to assume that an operation that writes to an `int` (via a pointer) won't affect an object that has type `long long`.

It is therefore legitimate of it to cache the value of `n` between the time it was originally assigned and the time at which it is subsequently printed. No *valid* write operation could have changed its value.

The particular switch and documentation to read is `-fstrict-aliasing`.

Comment: Beat me to it :) Wikipedia gives some explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing where one can read *In C++, pointer arguments are assumed not to alias if they point to fundamentally different types ("strict aliasing" rules). This allows more optimizations to be done than in C.* Note that there is a special rule for `char*` which is allowed to alias any pointer.

Comment: @Matthieu: what's Wikipedia on about, "more optimization than in C"? C has strict aliasing rules too (since C99), although to be honest I've never actually compared with C++ side-by-side to check they're the same. If I'm doing something borderline I either (a) don't, or else (b) become a temporary expert on the rules for the language I'm doing it in, and then forget the exact details again shortly afterwards.

Comment: @Steve: actually, if you get to the article, they have distinguished C and C99 (`restrict`). As I am no C expert (C++ is already difficult enough for my lil' brain), I'd be hardpressed to answer your question though!

Comment: @Matthieu: ah, right, so the Wikipedia article is merely more out of date than the age of Wikipedia. Happens ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You're breaking strict aliasing. Compiling with -Wall should give you a `dereferencing type-punned pointer` warning. See e.g. http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html

Answer (score 1):

I get the same results with GCC 4.4.4 on Linux/i386.

The program's behavior is undefined, since it violates the strict aliasing rule.